# Wordpress: Center aligning "Read More"

Tags: wordpress, alignment, center

I've created a child theme of Wordpress twentysixteen theme. I have some problems center aligning the Read More text/button. With the help of Chrome Developer Tool I've found that the class that controls the link is called "more-link". In my child style.css I've added the following code:

```
.more-link {
display: inline-block;
white-space: normal;
border-radius: 3em;
border: 1px solid #ff7788;
padding: 1em;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
clear: both;
}
```

I've tried everything, however nothing works.

However it works when I write for example: margin-left: 30px;
float: right also works.

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VqiL.png
See image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caFMy.png

Comment: try to add following css code into your child theme css: `.more-link { display: block !important; }`

Comment: It can't be displayed as a block because I'm using a border around it. It has to be inline or inline-block. I tried using important to inline-block with no luck.

Comment: please show me how it look once you use my css code.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/caFMy.png

Comment: thanks for the screenshot, please try this now:

`.more-link { 
display: block !important; 
width: 35%;
}`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! But I still don't understand why any of the methods I used didn't work. Especially the 'display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;'

Comment: dear @Anna , i have post it as an answer, please accept it, it would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

try to add following css code into your child theme **style.css** file:

```
.more-link { 
display: block !important; 
width: 35%; 
}
```